# What can I do if I spot an EV certificate being misused?

Tags: certificates

While helping my family with their computer problems, I found a malicious executable signed by a valid EV certificate. The executable is flagged as malicious by a majority of engines on VirusTotal, and I have also run it in a sandboxed environment and witnessed some questionable behavior.

Now, I can't say I'm very familiar with the issue, but my impression is that Extended Validation means the subject of the certificate, and the way they use the certificate, should be vigorously examined. I wonder if there is anything I can do apart from reporting it to AV manufacturers? For large, well-known CAs, is there a policy/term that prevents such certificate usage? Should I notify the issuing certificate authority of such cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Extended Validation means that CA vendor did a thorough background check of certificate requester/owner authenticity and legal business. This means that CA assures that certificate was issued to a legal business. EV doesn't make any assumptions whether the code signed by that certificate is legal or virus-free.

However, if you find that binary code is signed with EV certificate, the signature is valid (the code isn't tampered) and code's behavior is malicious, you may contact issuer CA vendor and provide all relevant information. There is a non-zero chance that certificate owner was hacked/breached and certificate is leaked to unauthorized person. Contacting CA is a good way for you.